# Regression for hierarchical time series

Tags: time-series, multilevel-analysis, unevenly-spaced-time-series

I have a dataset with time series A, B and C from different countries. These time series have different starting points, missing values, and irregular intervals (only weekdays).

Instead of forecasting, I want to know if time series A can be explained by time series B and C, similar to a multiple regression.

As far as I have understood, hierarchical time series (or grouped time series?) is the way to go here. However, I only find texts and tutorials on forecasting, but not on regressions. What is the best way to investigate the assumed relationships? Is there such a thing as correlations between hierarchical time series?

I have started to mess with the hts package in R but I have trouble setting up the data structure. I would be happy for links to R or python packages or tutorials.